Numpythonic way of the inverse of sliding_window_view
I have original array test:
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

test = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]).reshape(-1,7) # (batch_size, seq_len) -> (2,7)
slided = sliding_window_view(test, window_shape=(3,), axis=-1).copy()
print(test, test.shape)
print(slided, slided.shape)

Outputting:
[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11 12 13 14]] (2, 7)

[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 2  3  4]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 5  6  7]]

 [[ 8  9 10]
  [ 9 10 11]
  [10 11 12]
  [11 12 13]
  [12 13 14]]] (2, 5, 3)

Given copied of slided array that was computed by sliding_window_view returning shape (batch_size, num_win, win_len), how do I reconstruct back into original array test with the shape of (batch_size, seq_len)?

If you actually have a copy of a sliding window view, things get more awkward. With a sliding window view, it's fairly straightforward to reconstruct the original shape and strides to take a new view equivalent to the original array (or follow the base chain to get the actual original array, but it can be tempting to hardcode too many sliding_window_view implementation details that way). With a copy, that doesn't work any more.

@user2357112 Suppose I keep the information of all arguments of sliding_window_view? Like original_shape, strides, window_shape, and etc. Will it work?

Doesn't help. The problem is that the copy has an entirely different memory layout.

Since you have a copy instead of the original sliding window view, you can't just reconstruct the shape and strides to reconstruct the original data. The copy has the wrong memory layout for that to work - the strides would have to change midway through a dimension.
But two views of your array put together can reconstruct the original data, so if we copy two such views into a new array, we get an array equivalent to the original:
import numpy

def unslide(arr):
    shape = arr.shape[:-2] + (arr.shape[-2] + arr.shape[-1] - 1,)
    view_1 = arr[..., 0]
    view_2 = arr[..., -1, 1:]

    res = numpy.empty(shape=shape, dtype=arr.dtype)
    res[..., :view_1.shape[-1]] = view_1
    res[..., view_1.shape[-1]:] = view_2

    return res

Looking at one "layer" of your array:
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 2  3  4]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 5  6  7]]

we're effectively putting together the first column and last row of that layer to reconstruct that part of the original array, and doing that for every layer. view_1 handles the first column (of every layer), and view_2 handles the last row.

Is it general answer? I mean beyond of my question, the window_shape argument during sliding can be multidimensional? And also for another args.

@MuhammadIkhwanPerwira: This can be generalized to handle that, but it'd take more work.
